# How do you come up with a good name for a website or software you are building?

Tags: naming

How do i come up with a good name for a website or software I am developing. Are there references for naming websites or software?

Comment: put an x at the end of your name. Linus -> Linux :-D

Comment: Ask yourself why you're giving it a name and what purpose you want that name to serve? Is it going to be receiving press coverage, or just being used internally? Are you aiming for consumers, or B2B. Questions like these will influence your decision.

Answer (score 4):

think of a rude word to use as an acronym, and then fit in the words to make that acronym fit.

SHAFTED was the code name of one internal project I was working on

```
Shipment
Help
And
Full
Tracking of
Export
Documentation
```

OTIS was the clean version I used around managers (Order Tracking Information System)

Answer (score 0):

I let my creativity flow and write up 5-10 names.
Then i google them.If one of them is not in use, i take it. :)
I want to be the names unique ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally? I don't, they're all horrible. But after a couple days of working on the project it's just a group of letters that means "work left to do," regardless of what I called it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea from Paul Graham's [Why Smart People Have Bad Ideas](http://www.paulgraham.com/bronze.html) essay,

> [4] I wrote a program to generate all
>   the combinations of "Web" plus a three
>   letter word. I learned from this that
>   most three letter words are bad:
>   Webpig, Webdog, Webfat, Webzit,
>   Webfug. But one of them was Webvia; I
>   swapped them to make Viaweb.